# Is a land a colourless spell?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I know lands are colourless, but is a land a colourless spell? Would it activate [Molten Nursery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Molten%20Nursery) or any other card that is activated with a colourless spell?

Comment: By the way, lands aren't always colorless, they could be colored when stated. I believe Dryad Arbor is the only colored land from the top of my head though. And of course if you have something like Painter's Servant on the battlefield

Comment: Mycosynth Lattice??

Comment: @Nathan Taylor, That won't make a difference. 305.9. If an object is both a land and another card type, it can be played only as a land. It can’t be cast as a spell.

Answer (score 15):

Lands are never spells, even if they have other types like [Dryad Arbor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dryad%20Arbor).

> **305.1.** A player who has priority may play a land card from his or her hand during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty. Playing a land is a special action; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule 115). Rather, the player simply puts the land onto the battlefield. Since the land doesn’t go on the stack, **it is never a spell**, and players can’t respond to it with instants or activated abilities.

> **305.9.** If an object is both a land and another card type, it can be played only as a land. It can’t be cast as a spell.

Answer (score 10):

Lands are not spells. They have no mana cost and you do not cast them. [Rule 305.1](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Lands) describes how lands are played:

> A player who has priority may play a land card from his or her hand during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty. Playing a land is a special action; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule 115). Rather, the player simply puts the land onto the battlefield. **Since the land doesn’t go on the stack, it is never a spell**, and players can’t respond to it with instants or activated abilities.